# Is there a good way to inflate cardview layout with another linear in a loop?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout-inflater

I'm try to create a `ListView` with `CardView`. `CardView` contains always 3 rows with some info, but after  that it got 2n rows that looks like:
- position, name;
- image, data, image, data.
I'm using for this task object, that contains:
- object with data, that will always fill fist 3 rows;
- list of object, that i use for 2n rows.

I've tried already:
- swapping `RecyclerAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter` (helps with visibility that I change too, but not with inflating);
- creating a method that will handle all logic related to inflating that layout
- inflating inside `onBindViewHolder/getView`

I will paste version with inflating `CardView` in another method:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {    

        /*inflating layout and fill it with data from first object*/
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        //add data

        //if needed to make sure that inflating will occur once. list is 
        //LinearLayout inside CardView, current is entire object
        if(list.getChildCount() < 1)
                addList(list, current);


        //setting click listeners and returning view
    }

 private void addList(ViewGroup parent, ListItem current){
        for (Item var : ListItem.getItemList()) {
            View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_part, parent, false);

            //setting data

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            parent.addView(layout);
        }
    }
```

@EDIT: `CardView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="25dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:id="@+id/type"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                android:id="@+id/show_list"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hide"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/hide_list"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Actual results:
- if i comment

```
if(list.getChildCount() < 1)
```

data fill be sometimes added few time, not only from correct object.
- now with that `if` layout is inflating with wrong data.
Expected result:
Inflating inside `CardView` add data that is correct for object and connected to it list of objects.

@EDIT2:
I've tried to just create that part of `View` manually instead of using `LayoutInflater`. That does not change anything.

Comment: Please, share your card xml. Also, you are inflating twice your `R.layout.card` in `getView`. Please, edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some break from this topic I found way to do it. Adapter reusing old `View` on `getView`/`onBindViewHolder`. If `Linear Layout` that conatins earlier list of others elements like `TextView`, `ImageView` etc. was not cleared before adding new elements, old will stay. 
The solustion is to remove old ones. On `Linear Layout` I needed to call `removeAllViews()`  before adding new elements.